# Systemd: How to automatically start instantiated services after reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I have a systemd service file `my_service@.service` like the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=...
After=network.target

[Service]
User=...
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/...
ExecStart=...
Restart=always
RestartSec=1s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I start then multiple instances like this:

```
sudo systemctl start my_service@a
sudo systemctl start my_service@b
sudo systemctl start my_service@c
```

Unfortunately, when the server reboots, they don't get started again and I have to manually run the above commands one more time.
Before I started using instantiated services, the service would automatically start.

Is there a way to make sure that all instances get started again when the machine reboots? Or should I take another approach for achieving that?

Versions: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, systemd 237

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, forgot that I had to run `enable` in addition to `start`:

```
sudo systemctl enable my_service@a
sudo systemctl enable my_service@b
sudo systemctl enable my_service@c
```